# Ways to export log-data from Azure Application Insights to the Elastic Stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

is there a way to export Log-Data from Application Insights to Elasticsearch?

Application Insights is monitoring my Elastic-Cluster.

I want to be able to export those logs to Elasticsearch. I was thinking that setting up a continuous export to sql with stream analytics might work if I then connect the sql-db with logstash.

But this seems unnecessarily complicated.

Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated. Ty in advance.

Edit for clarification: I want to export the Application Insights Data to a seprate Azure/Elastic Cluster.

Comment: try this:   https://keyholesoftware.com/2021/06/23/bridging-the-gap-azure-app-insights-to-on-prem-elastic-stack/